# Shortening vectors (within a data.frame) mutiplication code in R

Tags: r, vector, matrix, dataframe

I have this code to do a series of multiplication and addition in R. Could someone give me a suggestion to use *apply to make it neater and shorter?

I looked around with keywords such as "series", "multiplication" but did not get anywhere. If this question has been posted before, please let me know the link. Thank you.

df1n is a `data.frame` with >78 variables and 215 observation.

```
dff[,3]<-(df1n[5]*((df1n[25]*df1n[26]*df1n[27]) + (df1n[28]*df1n[29]*df1n[30]) +
         (df1n[31]*df1n[32]*df1n[33]) + (df1n[34]*df1n[35]*df1n[36]) + 
         (df1n[37]*df1n[38]*df1n[39]) + (df1n[40]*df1n[41]*df1n[42]) +
         (df1n[61]*df1n[62]*df1n[63]) + (df1n[64]*df1n[65]*df1n[66]) + 
         (df1n[67]*df1n[68]*df1n[69]) + (df1n[70]*df1n[71]*df1n[72]) + 
         (df1n[73]*df1n[74]*df1n[75]) + (df1n[76]*df1n[77]*df1n[78]))
         )
```

Regards,
ikel

Comment: Is there any logic to the array indexing? What are you trying to achive?

Comment: Hi Moe, it is a formula of calculating values based on other values in the data.frame. The only logic I can think of is that it begins at 25 then do multiplication for next 3 column, then add to the next multiplication of three columns, until 40. Then it starts again looking at 61 and repeat same pattern until clumn 76. I hope this is clear. I didn't know this is called array indexing. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `lapply()` to construct a list of indices for each of the `(A*B*C)` pieces. Then, pass those indices to `sapply`, extracting each set of elements from `df1n` and multiplying them with `prod()`. The rest is self-explanatory:

```
df1n <- 1:100
ll <- lapply(c(seq(25, 40, by=3), seq(61, 76, by=3)), 
             function(X) seq(X, by=1, length.out=3))
df1n[5] * sum(sapply(ll, function(i) prod(df1n[i])))
# [1] 11439180
```

---

**EDIT**: Now that I know that each element of `df1n` is a length-215 vector, here's the code I'd suggest instead:

```
# Example data (a list in which each element is a vector of length 215).
x <- replicate(100, 1:215, simplify=FALSE) 
ll <- lapply(seq(25, 76, by=3), function(X) seq(X, by=1, length.out=3))
res <- x[[5]] * rowSums(sapply(ll, function(i) Reduce("*", x[i])))

str(res)
# num [1:215] 18 288 1458 4608 11250 ...
```

Comment: Hi Josh, that's short~! I will give it a try and let you know soon~

Comment: @ikel -- I had missed that you weren't using the whole sequence from 25 to 76. I've edited it now so that it does the correct calculation.  My best advice is to just play around with the pieces to see how they work. And if this works for you, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark to its left. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, my df1[5] and other, each has 215 observations, and when I apply the formula (carefuly), it yields NA. I'll try again and let you know. I don't think "prod" is the right func to use.

Comment: @ikel -- You're right that `prod()` is not the right function, given that those elements are themselves vectors. To get element-wise multiplication of a list of vectors, you can use `Reduce("*", list(A, B, C))`. I've added a second set of code that may work for your data (though I can't know, since I haven't seen its structure). Cheers.

Comment: +1 Since I built upon your (first) great idea in my answer... ;-)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien -- Reduce("*", list(A,B,C)) is brilliant! I will give you the tick since you gave the idea first.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modification of Josh's solution that produces the same ouput as your original code on the sample data below.

```
# Some sample data
df1n <- as.data.frame( lapply(1:80, function(i) seq(i, len=5)) )

df1n[5] * rowSums(sapply(c(seq(25,40,3), seq(61,76,3)), 
    function(i) df1n[[i]]*df1n[[i+1]]*df1n[[i+2]]))
#  c.5..6..7..8..9.
#1         11439180
#2         14386680
#3         17580528
#4         21032640
#5         24755220
```

Comment: +1 for code that's less obfuscated and so better than either of my answers. Still, when I get it, I never can seem to pass up a chance to use `Reduce()`...

Comment: @Tommy -- Thanks for <- function(i) df1n[[i]]*df1n[[i+1]]*df1n[[i+2]]  ... human  readable ^_^